# graphql enum not defined in schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, enums, graphql

I am currently learning GraphQL and I have stumbled upon this error. How can I fix it while still using the GraphQLEnumType object.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');
const { GraphQLEnumType } = require('graphql');

const Bonus = new GraphQLEnumType({
    name: 'Bonus',
    values: {
        BIG: {
            value: "Big",
        },
        SMALL: {
            value: "Small",
        }
    },
});

const typeDefs = gql`

enum Bonus {
  BIG
  SMALL
}
`;

const resolvers = {
    Bonus : Bonus
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Following is the error:

> /home/jonas/Projects/javascript-questions-flow4b/backend/node_modules/graphql-tools/dist/generate/addResolveFunctionsToSchema.js:53
>                       throw new _1.SchemaError(typeName + "." + fieldName + " was defined in resolvers, but enum is not in schema");
>                       ^
>
> Error: Bonus.name was defined in resolvers, but enum is not in schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `GraphQLEnumType` if you're configuring ApolloServer using `typeDefs` and `resolvers`. Instead, if you want to provide custom values for your enum values, pass in the appropriate object as part of your `resolvers`, as shown in [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/scalars-enums#internal-values).

```
const resolvers: {
  Bonus: {
    BIG: 'Big',
    SMALL: 'Small', 
  },
}
```

Note that you only need to do this if you want to internally map the enum values to something other than their names. `BIG` will map to `"BIG"` and `SMALL` will map to `"SMALL"` by default, so if that's all you need, just don't include `Bonus` in your resolvers at all.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to do some more reading to fully understand this answer :)

Comment: I'm happy to provide additional details if this didn't fully answer your question. If you're building a server using Apollo, I would suggest sticking to their [extensive documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/schema). While Apollo uses GraphQL.js under the hood, most of the actual GraphQL.js documentation is not relevant when you're using Apollo.

Comment: yep, thats not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use GraphQLEnumType if you're configuring ApolloServer using typeDefs and resolvers.

Define BonusType as scalar in your typeDefs object:

```
const BonusType = new GraphQLEnumType({
    name: 'Bonus',
    values: {
        BIG: {
            value: "Big",
        },
        SMALL: {
            value: "Small",
        }
    },
});

const typeDefs = gql`

scalar BonusType
`;
```

Now whenever adding query for BonusType object you will get as result: 
1. Name of BonusType enum.
2. Value of the BonusType enum.

See https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-server/how-to-use-custom-enums~376c8da8-19a5-4338-9bee-4cba7a036d8f for more info